# How to consolidate code | making a variable Dynamic

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through an object and run all functions called init().

I have the following code but it is repetitive.  How do I effectively make MC and Su instances of a variable?

Here is the repetitive code.

```
MC.initAll = function() {
    for ( var key in MC ) {
        if( MC.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            if( MC[key].hasOwnProperty( 'init' ) ) {
                MC[key].init();
            }
        }
    }
    for ( var key in Su ) {
        if( Su.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            if( Su[key].hasOwnProperty( 'init' ) ) {
                Su[key].init();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are many options...

- Put them in an array and then pop them out via a for loop.
- Make them object properties and loop through the object properties.
- Make a function call and pass them in as parameters.
- Use an Object Map per fritz below

Which is best or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var iterate = [MC, Su], l = iterate.length, i, key;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    for( key in iterate[i]) {
        if( iterate[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && iterate[i][key].hasOwnProperty("init")) {
            iterate[i][key].init();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function _iterateAndCallInit(objectToIterateOver)
{
    for ( var key in objectToIterateOver ) {
        if( objectToIterateOver.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            if( objectToIterateOver[key].hasOwnProperty( 'init' ) ) {
                objectToIterateOver[key].init();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ps: probably it also makes sense to check if type of `objectToIterateOver[key].init` is function

```
typeof objectToIterateOver[key].init == 'function'
```

Comment: @Hiro Protagonist: just a habit of making utility-like functions "private"

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't overthink it. Just a general map function would do:

```
function object_map(my_object, callback) {
    for (var property in my_object) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(my_object, property)) {
            callback(my_object[property]);
        }
    }
}

object_map(MC, function (item) {
    item.init();
});
object_map(Su, function (item) {
    item.init();
});
```

This reduces all the overhead of looping over elements in an object (and the potential `hasOwnProperty` pitfall (that I have corrected ;) ). And just focuses on what is important at this abstraction level.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function) `In many programming languages, map is the name of a higher-order function that applies a given function to each element of a list, returning a list of results. It is often called apply-to-all when considered in functional form. This is an example of homomorphism.` The function I wrote doesn't return anything, though it would be easy enough to add.

Comment: This is what they're generally called, might as well start using the name :)